# Update Magento 2.3.3 with Composer 2

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer

I manage a multisite system for work, with Magento 2.3.3 Community Edition
My hosting is managed, and they recently rolled out Composer 2 for all customers on their hosting.

I'm trying to update the site, plugins etc however I'm encountering lots of problems which seem to stem from Composer 2 as I consistently get the error

```
You are using Composer 2, which some of your plugins seem to be incompatible with. Make sure you update your plugins or report a plugin-issue to ask them to support Composer 2
```

I'm unable to roll back to composer 1, and trying to update dependencies has me going round in a loop of unsatisfiable plugins

```
Problem 1
- magento/composer-root-update-plugin is locked to version 1.0.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
- magento/composer-root-update-plugin 1.0.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
Problem 2
- magento/product-community-edition is locked to version 2.3.3 and an update of this package was not requested.
- magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.0 -> your php version (7.4.28) does not satisfy that requirement.
Problem 3
- Root composer.json requires dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer ^0.5.0 -> satisfiable by dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer[v0.5.0].
- dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer v0.5.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
Problem 4
- magento/framework 102.0.3 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.0 -> your php version (7.4.28) does not satisfy that requirement.
- yireo/magento2-webp2 0.8.0 requires magento/framework ^101.0.1|^101.1|^102.0|^103.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.3].
- yireo/magento2-webp2 is locked to version 0.8.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

I've tried updating each plugin individually but always seem to get routed back to the same few core componenets that also don't update.

I realise this isn't a programming issue, but would appreciate any help or sensible suggestions on how to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is related to composer you can downgrade the composer using these steps:

1. Run this command on your magento root
   wget https://getcomposer.org/download/1.10.17/composer.phar

2.then run the commands with composer.phar instead of direct composer :
php -dmemory_limit=4G composer.phar clearcache
php -dmemory_limit=4G composer.phar update

and also you need to downgrade your php to 7.3

Comment: I think my host controls the Composer version ~ at the moment no upgrade / downgrade commands are successful through the CLI but I appreciate the idea

Comment: That's why I suggested wget , it will work like portable composer instead of installation

Comment: Downgrading composer seems to be the way forward, I've asked my host to perform this for me and I'm working on the updates now. Thankyou